Nodemailer sends SMTP emails locally but not on vercel production build
thanks in advance for the help. I'm having issues with nodemailer and my SMTP email that I connected to a contact form. When I was using gmail with an app password, it worked on both my local and vercel build but with the new email it's not working. The new email works only locally now, I get a 500 error when the form is submitted on the production build
Here is my code for the email api:
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const { email, name, message } = await request.json();

    const htmlContent = `
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>
            /* You can add CSS styles here for the email content */
            body {
              font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
              font-size: 16px;
            }
            .container {
              max-width: 600px;
              margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .subject {
              color: #b02d1f;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div class="container">
            <h2 class="subject">New Message From Contact Form</h2>
            <p><strong>Name:</strong> ${name}</p>
            <p><strong>Email:</strong> ${email}</p>
            <p><strong>Message:</strong> ${message}</p>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
    `;

    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "example.prod.iad2.secureserver.net",
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.MY_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.MY_PASSWORD,
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.MY_EMAIL,
      to: process.env.MY_EMAIL,
      subject: `New Message from ${name} (${email})`,
      html: htmlContent,
      replyTo: email,
    };

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          resolve('Email sent!');
        } else {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Email sent' });
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: err.message || "An error occurred" }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

send-email.ts:
import { FormData } from '@/components/ContactForm';

export function sendEmail(data: FormData) {
  const apiEndpoint = '/api/email';

  fetch(apiEndpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
}

I need the email to go directly to the SMTP server email. I also tried "secure: false" with "port: 587" but same issue. Will I be forced to use only gmail if I use nodemailer? If my contact form code, please let me know. Thank you!

Have you added your environment variables to vercel?

Yes, all of the variables are added. I want to mention this code works when I switch the service to google and use a gmail account

Kindly check the logs and add edit the post to add the relevent logs

There is a 500 server error when submitting the form, I don't see any other error. The server is correctly configured as when I run a telnet protocol in cmd it connects instantly

Vercel has limitations on outbound connections, especially to certain ports like 25, which is commonly used for SMTP. This could be causing the timeout error in your application.

please provide docs link also

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
